# Как подключить Ext JS 6 к Java Maven?

Tags: java, extjs

Я только начинаю разбираться с Ext JS(требуется для тестового задания), скачал триальную версию ext-6.0.2-trial. В гайдах подключение к библиотеке происходит указанием ссылки на 2 файла

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
```

Но я не могу найти эти папки.

P.S. Что бы работать с Ext JS в Java проекте надо ли основную папку ext-6.0.2 кидать куда-то или достаточно в index.html указать ссылки на эти файлы?

Comment: А причем тут java и maven? js - это статический ресурс. Куда файлы поместите, желательно в каталог относительно index.html, тот путь и указывайте.

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov я просто не могу понять куда я должен всю папку с фреймворком деть? на одном сайте пишут в папку сервера, на другом в папку проекта. на официальном все вообще через sencha cmd только объясняется.

Comment: Ну смотрите - если ваш проект таки java - то для хранения статики обычно принято использовать каталог `$project/src/man/resources` или `$project/src/man/webapp`, или еще где-то - зависит от java фреймворка и настроек приложения (откуда сервлет тянет статику, например `<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>default</servlet-name><url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>`).  Если у вас предполагается высокая нагрузка, то статику можно унести на nginx, который будет ее быстро отдавать, а к приложению обращаться только за данными через rest-api

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас понял, вам нужно через командную строку сгенерировать ваш extjs проект. Там вы укажите папку куда генерировать и папку с фреймворком.

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/extjs/framework generate app AppName path/to/app
```

Предварительно нужно установить sencha cmd

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно интегрировать extjs, то можно указать место хранения скаченной библиотеки. Для intellij только знаю надо зайти settings (ctrl + alt + S)
найти раздел Languages and Frameworks -> javascript -> libraries. В нем добавить новую библиотеку. Есть документация https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#configure сам новичок, мало чего знаю.